# Using offline collada2gltf converter to convert collada models with textures

Tags: gltf

My attached files are available here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0rh99fSDowtUERnWEhVUUFwOUk/view?usp=sharing

I have 3d models in collada ('**dhqg part 2.dae**') with matching textures (jpg pictures in '**dhqg part 2**' folder)

My command line for converting was: '**./collada2gltf -f 'filename.dae' -e 'TextureFolderName'**'.

I used option '**-e**' for embedding the texture folder but the result gltf file did not contain the textures in it and it was wrong.

If someone knows the answer for my trouble, please let me know.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag `-e` does not take an option. If you execute it like this...

```
./collada2gltf -f filename.dae -e
```

...the textures will be embedded in the resulting `.gltf` file. I tested that, and the textures were definitely there: the file was 117MB large, and contain entries for the textures. Unfortunately my browser tab crashes when trying to view that. :)